# Minimal Bookdown book does not render properly. How can i fix this issue?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, bookdown

I am following the instruction in Authoring Books with R Markdown relative reproducing to the minimal bookdown book.

Getting started.

https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/get-started.html

The easiest way for beginners to get started with writing a book with R Markdown and bookdown is through the demo bookdown-demo on GitHub:

1. Download the GitHub repository https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo as a Zip file, then unzip it locally.
2. Install the RStudio IDE. Note that you need a version higher than 1.0.0. Please download the latest version if your RStudio version is lower than 1.0.0.
3. Install the R package bookdown:
4. ## stable version on CRAN
5. install.packages("bookdown")
6. ## or development version on GitHub

## devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')

7. Open the bookdown-demo repository you downloaded in RStudio by clicking bookdown-demo.Rproj.
8. Open the R Markdown file index.Rmd and click the button Build Book on the Build tab of RStudio.

All is fine until I reach the point where it states ... "click the button Build Book on the Build tab of RStudio."

Problem: I can locate no 'Build' button.  As such, I Knit the document from within Index.Rmd.  The document renders but with no content in any of the pages except Index.Rmd.

This[linked](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ns8o21c6s7ghid0/11.jpg?dl=0) image is all the content I get.

I am running this version of R Studio.

RStudio
Version 1.4.904
© 2009-2020 RStudio, PBC
"Wax Begonia" (5a13c579, 2020-10-05) for macOS
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_16_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 1):

The `Build` tab is a tab in another pane in the RStudio IDE:

[image: The Build tab in RStudio]

It's not on the toolbar of the source editor.

Comment: That sets me on the right track.  Thanks.